# Copying file from ssh server to mac?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

This question has been repeated many times and I know to copy a file from ssh server to mac I should follow this:

> Copy the file "foobar.txt" from a remote host to the local host
>
> $ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory

But I want to know how can I copy that to my local machine after connecting to remote ssh.
I meant after connecting to ssh means in terminal I connect to ssh and then I copy them to my pc. what  I want to do is one time connect to ssh and enter password and then do all operation. Why? because I am writing a user friendly program which ask password one time and I don't want the user enter every time or save the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually trying to reuse existing ssh connection.

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` to set up automatical connection sharing:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r
```

Now, if you do

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

And if you already have a connection established in another terminal then it wont ask you for a password and connection will be established very quickly.

Comment: I'm just learning the basic, can you tell me what I should enter exactly? I tried to run first line and I got this error::   bash: ControlMaster: command not found

Comment: @Bernard you should edit ``~/.ssh/config`` with a text editor, like ``nano``, ``gedit`` or any other that you like. Simply type in these lines or copy paste them. For example: ``nano ~/.ssh/config`` this will open the file in the console text editor called ``nano``. So after you're done typing in these lines, press **ctrl+x** to exit from nano and then **y** to confirm your changes

Answer (score 0):

Not an SO question, but:

> http://kb.iu.edu/data/agye.html
>
> The syntax for the scp command is:

```
scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2`
```

In other words, just switch source/destination if you want to copy something in the other direction :)

For example:

```
scp foobar.txt your_username@remotehost.edu:some/directory
```

Comment: I meant after connecting to ssh means in terminal I connect to ssh and then I copy them to my pc. what you have written I have to put password after that. But I want to one time connect to ssh and then do all operation. Why? because I am creating a user friendly program which ask password one time and I don't want the user enter every time

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files from remote to local by sftp (secure file transfer protocol)
first init sftp

```
sftp -P typeYourPortNumber username@hostname
```

now you are inside of sftp terminal. now you can copy file by typing

```
get absolutePathToSouce absolutePathLocal
```

you also can transfer file to the server by

```
put pathToSource pathToDestination
```